Dynamically Build LINQ Expressions - ToLower and Contains at the same time
I struggle with adding ToLower() to the Contains LINQ Expressions:
Here is the code of mine with dynamic LINQ Expressions (Contains):
private static Expression GetExpressionCase<T>(ParameterExpression param, SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
{
    MethodInfo containsMethod =
        typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

    MemberExpression member =
        Expression.Property(param, searchCriteria.Key);

    ConstantExpression constant =
        Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(searchCriteria.Value, member.Type));

    switch (searchCriteria.Operation)
    {
        case '=':
            return Expression.Equal(member, constant);

        case '>':
            return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, constant);

        case '<':
            return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, constant);

        case ':':
            return Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, constant);
     }

     return null;
}

My codes works fine but i want to add ToLower() before Contains() like this query:
Current query looks likes this (Contains() only):
var test = context.Table.Where(x => x.Key.Contains("value"));

I hope query will look likes this (Added ToLower()):
var test = context.Table.Where(x => x.Key.ToLower().Contains("hoa"));

I've already tried using StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase but it can't be translated by the query provider (postgreSQL).

SQL comparisons are already case insensitive by default. And even if you have a non-default case-sensitive collation, ToLower() is NOT the correct way to make the case insensitive comparison.

why are you creating expressions instead of just writing the code? probably this is a part of bigger thing, but you can chaing things conditionally on IQueryable based on you SearchCriteria

@JoelCoehoorn In my case postgreSQL is not case-insensitive comparisons. I know Postgre has ILike, if i write straight down the query used ILike it works fine, but with Contain("key-word", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) the EF can not translates it

@JoelCoehoorn, if you work with PostgreSQL, only way to use case insensitive index is to call explictly lower function. So do not judge only from SQL Server side.

Try the following realisation. I have simplified it a little bit.
private static Expression? GetExpressionCase(ParameterExpression param, SearchCriteria searchCriteria, bool makeLower)
{
    Expression memberExpression = Expression.Property(param, searchCriteria.Key);

    if (makeLower && memberExpression.Type == typeof(string))
    {
        memberExpression = Expression.Call(memberExpression, nameof(string.ToLower), Type.EmptyTypes);
    }

    var searchValue = searchCriteria.Value;
    if (makeLower && searchValue is string str)
    {
        searchValue = str.ToLower();
    }

    var constant = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(searchValue, memberExpression.Type));

    switch (searchCriteria.Operation)
    {
        case '=':
            return Expression.Equal(memberExpression, constant);

        case '>':
            return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(memberExpression, constant);

        case '<':
            return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(memberExpression, constant);

        case ':':
            return Expression.Call(memberExpression, nameof(string.Contains), Type.EmptyTypes, constant);

        default:
            return null;
    }
}


Thanks you, this works well. Additional: i changed memberExpression = Expression.Call(memberExpression, nameof(string.ToLower), Type.EmptyTypes, memberExpression); to memberExpression = Expression.Call(memberExpression, nameof(string.ToLower), Type.EmptyTypes, null); to avoid throwing Exception - Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method

You're doing it well, I only would suggest simply chaining the result of the ToLower call with Contains.
case ':':
    MethodInfo containsMethod =
        typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Contains), new[] { typeof(string) });

    MethodInfo toLowerMethod =
        typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.ToLower), Type.EmptyTypes);

    MethodCallExpression toLowerCall = // X.ToLower();
        Expression.Call(member, toLowerMethod);

    MethodCallExpression containsCall = // X.Contains(Y);
        Expression.Call(toLowerCall, containsMethod, constant);

    return containsCall;


Thank you for your answer, this is a clever approach that i never thought. Unfortunately it throw an exc: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'System.String ToLower()' (Parameter 'method') when toLowerCall X.ToLower()

sure, because ToLower has no parameters. So instead of passing constant as last parameter, just omit it.
